# Should we allow "true muslim"?

Tags: discussion

The original heading to [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1240/44) was "What should a true muslim do if his daughter does not respect the faith" (I suggested an edit about this, it may or may not be accepted while you read this). The word "true" in the heading sounded wrong to me, and since the tone of the site is important, I wanted to carry the issue here.

The problem I have with the word "true" is that it implies that there are "true muslims" and "false muslims". I don't intend to argue if there is really "false muslims" or not, but regardless, such implacations seems a little belittling, or provacative to me, and can easily lead to debate and flaming. Therefore, I suggest that we discourage, if not ban, such pharases like `true muslim`, `real muslim` etc. What do you think?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a better word would have been "devout." I'm not sure the author was necessarily implying something derisive as *true* vs. *false* Muslims.

In the context of asking a question, an author might feel the need to write defensively; to preempt their question by *specifying* "for those who follow the teaching of Islam…" — as if every answer needs to qualify *"some people do not believe or follow these teachings, but for those who do… etc, etc."*

But regardless of intent, you can remove these types of qualifying words. They're not necessary, but I wouldn't jump to offense or get too draconian about it.

For the purpose of this site, we can assume the context of *all* posts is to cite ideal canon; that is, there is always an implied ***"…according to the teachings of Islam"*** in every post.

Answer (score 4):

I'm an outsider to the site, but these phrases seem to be *very* open to interpretation and sectarianism. They seem to invite debates over which sect/etc is "true".

On the other hand, you can ask the author to specify the sect in place of "true muslim". "What shoud a Sunni do if XYZ" seems OK (doesn't invite pointless fighting)

So I say it ought to be removed, and you can ask the author to specify a sect if he wants to.

Comment: I can't understand how it is related to sect

Comment: @tachyon Not _necessarily_ , in that case. But in general I've seen  cases where a Muslim of sect A doesn't consider sect B to be Islamic. I think that the phrase "true Muslim" could be abused to discriminate the sects. (though the phrase probably means "devout" like Robert said above)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think his intention is to split muslims into true muslims and fals muslims , AFAIK he mean what should a muslim do if ..... ,and he added the word true for strengthen his question ,  BTW it is better to remove such words to avoid ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the antonym of a true muslim could roughly mean a "[Munafiq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munafiq)". While the question you attached isn't talking about this apparently, some could use this word to relate to behaviours distinct from those of Munafiqs.

Answer (score 0):

Well the question has been closed and the issue has been address, but I will offer my take.

The word "true Muslim" was not used in the bad sense but rather in useful sense but it is just  not good english, although in some it does make sense. As suggested by Robert "devout muslim" is a good replacement. I would suggest to use "faithful Muslim" or "God fearing Muslim" to stress that the person really cares about his faith and is worried about his child's actions not being responsible enough?